# nil function called when button pressed

Tags: swift, firebase

I try to add a rating system to my project:

```
var userRating: userRating! {
    didSet {
        good.setTitle(" \(userRating.numberOfGood)", for: [])
    }
}

@IBAction func goodReview(_ sender: UIButton) {
    userRating.good() -> ERROR
    good.setTitle(" \(userRating.numberOfGood)", for: [])
}
```

userRating Class:

```
var numberOfGood = 0

func good() {
    numberOfGood += 1
}
```

But every time I click on the Button I'm getting **Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value** as an Error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the userRating var not instantiated as a UserRating class so it's 'good' function is nil. Here's some code to follow:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    class UserRatingClass {
        var numberOfGood = 0

        func good() {
            numberOfGood += 1
        }
    }

    var userRating: UserRatingClass! {
        didSet {
            let x = userRating.numberOfGood
            self.goodLabel.setTitle("rating: \(x)"
        }
    }
```

and in the viewDidLoad, set up the userRating

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.userRating = UserRatingClass() //this set up the var
```

and then in the button action

```
@IBAction func goodReview(_ sender: UIButton) {
    userRating.good()
    let x = userRating.numberOfGood
    self.goodLabel.setTitle("rating: \(x)"
}
```

Also, as mentioned in the other answers, please capitalize class names and it's usually good practice to refer to class vars with 'self.'

Comment: Is there a way to save it via Firebase? I tried **          ref.child("numberOfOkay").setValue(numberOfOkay)** but also there I'm getting nil...

Comment: @SwiftStarter1848 The code in my answer (or the question) isn't really related to Firebase so we would need to see where & how you are trying to store you Firebase data. I would suggest opening a new separate question with the code that isn't working and we can take a look. Be sure to include the problematic code , a description of what you expect and some information about what your Firebase structure should look like

Comment: Ok, I've done this - would be cool if you could check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59236420/set-value-of-user-rating-to-firebase-database

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you don't initialize the `userRating` var somewhere?

Please remember to write your class names with a capital letter, like this: `var userRating: UserRating`.

Comment: I'm calling it in the very first Line of Code given in my question :(

Answer (score 0):

This happens, because you don't initialise your userRating object at all. Just add this line to your viewDidLoad() method. `userRating = UserRating()`. Hope it will help you

Comment: But I'm already initializing it in the very first line of code

Comment: In that code, that you provide, you not initialise a variable, you just declare it