# set value of user rating to Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to send the voting from users to firebase and save them under the specific user.

```
class User: NSObject {
    var id: String?

    init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        self.id = dictionary["id"] as? String
    }

    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var numberOfGood = 0

    init(id: String? = nil) {
        self.id = id
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").childByAutoId()
    }

    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot){
        ref = snapshot.ref
        if let value = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
            numberOfGood = value["numberOfGood"] as! Int
        }
    }

    func save() {
        let postDictionary = [
            "id" : self.id,
            "numberOfGood" : self.numberOfGood,
            ] as [String : Any]
        self.ref.setValue(postDictionary)
    }
}
```

Inside the viewController where to vote I handle the voting itself like this:

```
class UserRatingClass {
    var numberOfGood = 0

    var ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").childByAutoId()

    func good() {
        numberOfGood += 1
        ref.child("numberOfGood").setValue(numberOfGood)
    }
}

var userRating: UserRatingClass! {
    didSet {
        let x = userRating.numberOfGood

        self.good.setTitle("\(x) ", for: [])

    }
}

 @IBAction func goodReview(_ sender: UIButton) {
    userRating.good()
    let x = userRating.numberOfGood
    self.good.setTitle("\(x) ", for: [])
}
```

I tried different ways like

```
    var StringGood = String(user?.numberOfGood)
    self.ref.child("users").child(StringGood).setValue(x)
```

inside the buttonActionFunction but by this I'm always getting **Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(Int?)'** as an error...

Edit: I call the User.swift class like this:

```
var user: User?
```

Comment: Off topic but why do you have three different initializers for the User class? Aren't you just init'ing the user from a Firebase Snapshot?

Comment: Also.... The code seems overly complex with potentially unneeded redundancies. we don't know the scope of the project but is the buttom line that users can upvote and downvote another user and you want to store the votes for each user?

Comment: to your second comment: exactly - I already got it working that users can only vote one time (but I haven't included the code as this is not needed I guess) and to your first comment: I honestly don't know haha it was the first project I ever worked on months ago and I now continue it for a uni project - don't ask em what I thought in first place as I coded this together

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing. But something is easy to spot is that you have childByAutoId in one of your references to the database. Are you sure you want to use that? Seems to me that you should find the user to which you are sending the vote and save the value under that entry in the database. childByAutoId will create a new user level entry for each vote that you cast,.

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla Good catch. The question is very unclear and the error mentioned (that's occurring in the buttonActionFunction) in the question is ambiguous as we don't know what line it's occurring on. Voting to close the question until we can get more clarity as to what the actual issue is.